# Discrepancy in the Zone information for the AKS metadata

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I was trying to access the Zone information for the worker nodes in AKS cluster and I see a discrepancy while accessing from the metadata and worker node labels.

**Zone info from the metadata URL:**

```
# curl -s "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/location?api-version=2021-05-01&format=text" -H "Metadata: true"
eastus

#curl -s "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/zone?api-version=2021-05-01&format=text" -H "Metadata: true"
1
```

**Zone info from the Labels:**

```
$ kubectl get nodes aks-agentpool-39829229-vmss000000 -o yaml | grep "topology.kubernetes.io"
    topology.kubernetes.io/region: eastus
    topology.kubernetes.io/zone: eastus-1
```

I understand that `1` is the correct zone, is there a specific reason to have different values in labels vs metadata API?

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.Compute` resource provider manages the Virtual Machines and Virtual Machine Scale Sets which create the underlying infrastructure for the Azure Kubernetes Service nodes. The Azure Kubernetes Service on the other hand, is provided by the `Microsoft.ContainerService` resource provider.

Now in `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` resource type can identify the value of the key `zones` only in string[] ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?tabs=json#property-values)) and the accepted values in the array are: 1, 2, 3 ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_create-optional-parameters)). Which is also why during creation of an AKS cluster or an AKS node pool the value of `zones` is a string[] and the accepted values in the array are: 1, 2, 3 ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az_aks_create-optional-parameters))

Now the *cloud-controller-manager* sets the label [`topology.kubernetes.io/zone`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#topologykubernetesiozone), which is a **Kubernetes node label** set to the **Kubernetes node resource** (this node/label information resides as a key value pair in the ETCD server of the Kubernetes cluster). The cloud controller manager in Azure (managed by `Microsoft.ContainerService`) is set to use a different nomenclature than `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines`'s `zone` field when setting the `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` labels for AKS nodes. E.g.  `topology.kubernetes.io/zone: eastus-1` if the underlying VM is in the *East US* region and in Availability Zone *1*.

To summarize, [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux) on an AKS node provides information about currently running **virtual machine instances** and **not the Kubernetes node object**. On the other hand kubectl get nodes fetches **Kubernetes node** information from the **Kubernetes ETCD**. The nomemclature differences between `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` zone field and `Microsoft.ContainerService` managed cloud controller manager's `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` labelling on the Kubernetes node object is what is manifested in your observation.